# Prove column space is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-verification

I have an exercise on my last assignment for linear algebra, which is the following:

> The *column space* $C(A)$ of linear mapping $A: \mathbb{R}^m
>  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by:
>
> $$C(A) = \{ \vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n : \exists \vec{x} \in
>  \mathbb{R}^m,  \text{with}:\vec{y} = A\vec{x} \}$$
>
> Prove that $C(A)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

So, I thought I need to prove the 2 properties of being a subspace:

1. Being closed under addition: $\forall x, y \in A \rightarrow (a + b) \in A$
2. Being closed under scalar multiplication: $\forall x \in A \land \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \alpha x \in A$

Where $A$ is a subspace.

To prove the first point, I just tried to follow the definition. Let's see.

1. Let $\vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\vec{z} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let also $\vec{y} = A \vec{x_1}$, where $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

   We want to prove that $\exists \vec{x_2} \in \mathbb{R}^m$, such that: $$\vec{y} + \vec{z} = A \vec{x_2}$$

   We know that: $$\vec{y} = A \vec{x_1}$$

   Now, we can do some math manipulations, starting from what we know:

   $$\vec{y} + \vec{z} = A \vec{x_1} + \vec{z}$$

   Just added $\vec{z}$ to both sides.

   Now we want to show that:

   $$A \vec{x_1} + \vec{z} = A \vec{x_2}$$
   $$A \vec{x_2} - A \vec{x_1} = \vec{z}$$
   $$A(\vec{x_2} - \vec{x_1}) = \vec{z}$$

   Now let's replace what we discover in the equation above:

$$\vec{y} + \vec{z} = A \vec{x_1} + A(\vec{x_2} - \vec{x_1})$$
$$\vec{y} + \vec{z} = A (\vec{x_1} + \vec{x_2} - \vec{x_1})$$
$$\vec{y} + \vec{z} = A (\vec{x_2})$$

Which is what we wanted to prove. Is this correct? If Yes, if I follow a similar reasoning for the second point, should I do also the trick?

Comment: It should be a lot shorter than that. Given $\vec y, \vec z \in C(A)$, let $\vec x_1, \vec x_2 \in \Bbb R^m$ be such that $A\vec x_1 = \vec y$ and $A\vec x_2 = \vec z$. Then $ \vec y + \vec z = A\vec x_1 + A\vec x_2 = A(\vec x_1 + \vec x_2)$. Done.

Comment: There is one more thing to check, namely that $C(A)$ is nonempty.

Comment: It means that the vector $(\vec x_1+\vec x_2)$ is sent by $A$ to $(\vec y +\vec z)$, and you wanted to prove that there is such a vector. Note that I haven't arrived at the point $A(\vec x_1 +\vec x_2)$, I've arrived at $\vec y +\vec z=A(\vec x_1 +\vec x_2)$

Answer (score 4):

You get things halfways and/or backwords, I guess.

You start with $\vec y$ and $\vec z$ not in $\mathbb R^n$, but more specifically in $C(A)$! By this you know that there exists $\vec x\in\mathbb R^m$ with $\vec y =A\vec x$ and there exists $\vec w\in\mathbb R^m$ with $\vec z=A\vec w$. Thus by linearity of $A$, 
$$\vec y+\vec z = A\vec x+A\vec w= A(\vec x+\vec w)\in C(A)$$
as desired.

The same method works for scalar multiples.

And finally, your conditions 1 and 2 ar *not* sudfficient to show that you have a subspace! You are missing a tiny (albeit rather trivial) third condition ...